# Unknown Thread pools being created

Tags: spring-boot, threadpool, jestjs, spring-boot-actuator

We have spring boot micro service with several libraries as dependencies. e.g Jest (elastic search), Hikari, Spring-Rabbit, FasterXml and many more.

After analyzing thread dump we found that 2 unknown pools are being created. On the normal development machine, these pools contain 8 to 10 threads. But on prod environment, we observed each of the pool has 66 threads. Thread pool name is auto-generated like pool-7, pool-2 etc.

We want to find out which java class/library is creating this thread pool and spawning the threads. Tried with oracle flight recorder, but even there we could no see the origin for these threads.

Can someone pls suggest the way to find out who is creating these threads?

Thanks,
Smita

Answer (score 1):

It's unfortunate that the Threat Start event in Flight Recorder doesn't record the stack trace from the Thread#start method. I will see if it can be added to a future JDK release. You should however be able to see the thread that starts new threads.

If you can't find other tools to help you, the only way I can think of is to instrument the java.lang.Thread#start method yourself. Either using bytecode instrumentation, or just clone OpenJDK, modify the source file for java.lang.Thread and build your own custom JDK. The last step may sound daunting, but it's not that hard if you are on JDK 8 or later.

```
hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8
cd jdk8
bash get_source.sh
bash configure
make images
```

When you clone, there is a README file in the root that will point you to further instructions, if you should run into problems.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. But as of now I got my thread name printed in logs, and enabled debug logs. Logs with thread Id helped to find the culprit.